# How do you extract the full list of files in a GEO archive?

Tags: chip-seq, geoquery, geo

I am new to use of GEO and having trouble figuring out a straightforward way to grab the names of the files,  (through programmable handles like GEOparse or otherwise) that is the entire and complete list of all files fastq and otherwise (NOT downloading the actual data, but the names and descriptions) within a specific GEO archive (GSEXXX). Albeit with the intention of categorizing the data into  more understandable and friendly to browsing segments, the data presentation in a GEO archive seems very fragmented, making it hard to find what you are looking for. When you submit your data to GEO, they require you to have a spreadsheet, that is essentially the list of files you are submitting with their corresponding meta-data descriptions. Is it possible to get that exact submission spreadsheet associated with a data archive?

Comment: Thank you very much @Sam, that looks very relevant. Just a superficial exam and experiment with geofetch has proven more helpful than GEOParse approach. I am not able to get the list of fastq files using --just-metadata so far, BUT I am able to  the processed file list such as peak files. I will play around with it more to see if I can crack fastq files also and I think that would completely answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely that you will be able to get the original submission spreadsheet, but you can use [Geofetch](http://geofetch.databio.org/en/latest/)